# Visual Studio trigger code generator for .NET MAUI

Tags: visual-studio, maui

Quite often it takes quite some time for Visual Studio to notice variable defined via `x:Name` in an XAML file. Is there a way to trigger this process code generation manually? Something like "refresh" or "generate code"?

It's annoying because VS doesn't complete my code even if it compiles a project. I end up with temporary assigning that value to a local variable with defined type... but this is not a way to go:)

```cs
    View view = MyRealControlDefinedViaXName;
    view.FadeTo(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

It belongs to the Visual Studio Editor. You can check this document about the [Features of the code editor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/writing-code-in-the-code-and-text-editor?view=vs-2022).